# How to get the local time from mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i'm new to mysql. i'm working on ruby on rails project. i'm using mysql database which store time in utc format. But i want localtime on india.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the time in the DB in utc.  You can always convert the time to the local time.

Look more into Rails Timezones, there is lots of information on it and it's well supported.

Essentially, you will set the Time.zone value based on the user in an around_filter or based on an environment setting, and Rails will take care of displaying dates in the correct time zone.

There are lots of other details, but that should get you started.